# How to change column name in huge dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to change the column name of the dataframe which has 128 coloumns. I want to iteratively change it. Example, I want it to be facefeat_1,facefeat_2,.....facefeat_128. Help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: `df.columns = [f'facefeat_{x}' for x in range(1,129)]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that `df` is your `DataFrame` variable. It should be like this.

```
df.columns = ['facefeat_'+str(i) for i in range(1,129)]
```